# How can I use Pandas to write a table using different lists as header and index and body to Excel?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I should create a Table that first column is a string, that the first one is 'Filename' and the rest is a list of the filenames in a directory (dimension n).

Then I should have a header row that contains a list that for each column indicates the name of that column (length of this list is m), and then between all this there is a list of float numbers that will be `m x n`.

How should I do this? In the most tutorials, there is only one of headers or the first column a list.

Here is what I have done. I add that the variable Filenames contains the strings that are the name of the files and casename is the first row and minmax is the m x n matrix of floats:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl as pyx
import numpy as np
from collections import OrderedDict

maxmin = [1,2,3,4,5,6,11,22,33,44,55,66,111,222,333,444,555,666]

Filenames=['A','B','C']
casename=['Xmax','Xmin','Ymax','Ymin','Zmax','Zmin']
Body = OrderedDict([ ('Filename', casename),(Filenames, maxmin) ] )

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Body)
```

[image: The output should look like this:]

Comment: can you just show us some sample data ?

Comment: Sure, I just added a minimal code

Comment: It is not important that maxmin be a matrix, but it's better to be, I have written it in the form of a list, but the output I need remains the same

Comment: Anything missing from given inputs? please let me know

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti, do you have example output?

Comment: Sure, I added it now

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti - Not sure if understand, but need `df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(maxmin).reshape(-1, len(casename)),
                  index=Filenames,
                  columns=casename)` ?

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried it with a simple case of Filenames = ['A','B'], casename=['Xmax','Xmin']
maxmin=[1,2,3,4], and it worked, in my case Filenames are 8 files and casename has 12 members

Comment: So it had to work , but I get the error : ValueError: Shape of passed values is (12, 1), indices imply (12, 8)

Comment: just corrected the casename, it has 12 members

Comment: I did 
mydata=np.array(maxmin).reshape(-1, len(casename))
df = pd.DataFrame([mydata], index=Filenames, columns=casename)

Comment: ValueError: Must pass 2-d input

Comment: Actually there was no need to this, I ran it again without [] and it worked !!